# Echo variable from phpmailer in template

Tags: php, phpmailer

How can i pass a variable from phpmailer to contents.php (template file) ? I need to pass the `$email` variable.

```
$mail -> msgHTML(file_get_contents('contents.php'), dirname(__FILE__));
```

contents.php

```
<div>
    This email was sent by x. <a href="www.x.com/process_contact.php?email="<?php echo $email ?> Unsubscribe </a>from this email.
</div>
```

Comment: You can't, not in the way you do it (which will not execute the PHP in contents.php, so it's probably not what you want anyway). There is likely a deeper architectural issue here, consider elaborating a bit deeper on what you are trying to do

Comment: @Pekka웃 The problem is a basic thing. I have a template with html code, but in Unsubscribe url i need to have the email from the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace a known tag with your email:

```
$email = 'your@email.com';
$mail -> msgHTML(str_replace('[emailhere]', $email, file_get_contents('contents.php')), dirname(__FILE__));
```

contents.php

```
<div>
    This email was sent by x. <a href="www.x.com/process_contact.php?email=[emailhere]"> Unsubscribe </a>from this email.
</div>
```

Manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php